# ConnectionString for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have xampp installed in my computer. I am trying to access data with ADO.Net. The  connection string I am using is given below:

```
string connectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = magento; User Id = magento; Password = abcd;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string cmdString = "SELECT date_added,title,description,url FROM adminnotification_inbox";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"prog");
dt = ds.Tables["prog"];
currRec = -1;
totalRec = dt.Rows.Count;
button3.Enabled = true;
```

I am able to log in with the above user id and password in phpmyadmin, but cannot access the database with the above connection string. please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: @A.V. I am following a c# ebook which has not got any such thing mentioned.

Comment: @marc_s I think he's trying the other way around - from .net to access the mySql of xamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has its own ADO.NET connector: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html#downloads

If you use that, you can create a MySqlConnection: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html

The basic SqlConnection is used for Microsoft's own SQL Server products.

Answer (score 0):

9-22-14 - Hope others see this if you don't:

You need a driver in your connect string I believe. "MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver" is the Window's driver name.

string connectionString ="Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER= .... ok put the rest of your connect string here.

Note: this is the string to connect to a MySQL db using MS Access VBA:

Dan